# In list view how to set by default to see all records without click on go button?

Tags: visualforce, administration

when we clicking on a tab -In list view ,we select all and clicking on go button , in our case - by default it should show all trades(select all option ) as default . how can we achieve this?

Comment: What do you mean show all - do you mean all the records in one long list with no pagination? List views are easy to set up with View all records but other factors can affect visibility of records such as Sharing Rules (OWD) and Role hierarchies.

Comment: I mean in list view  there is trade all option we have , beside that there is go button , we dont need to click on go ,it should directly land on trade all while clicking on that tab(object)

Comment: HOWEVER, in order to get to my customized view the user must click [Go!] after opening the tab. How do I get my custom view to display by default?

Answer (score 0):

You can implement this by visualforce.
Please refer this **[post](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/81169/redirect-to-list-view-url-on-custom-object-tab-click)**.

Comment: But it is still not changing

Comment: Did you get any issues?

Comment: Not facing issues,its still not resolved , any other ideas?